# How to write value inside excel file using iterator

Tags: java

```
Iterator<ArrayList<E>> iterator = (Iterator<ArrayList<E>>) rraylist.iterator();
int ro=1;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    col=0;
    Row row=sheet.createRow(ro++);
    ArrayList<E> innerlist = iterator.next();
    Iterator<E> innerIterator = innerlist.iterator();
    while (innerIterator.hasNext()) {

        //System.out.println(innerIterator.next());// if i am displaying  value on console then value are getting displayed

        row.createCell(col++).setCellValue(innerIterator.next());
        //here when i want to store into excel sheet then getting exception 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: Please format your code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K. Also, provide some more information (which you will have to, because questions cannot be only code).